# How do I Pipe in Skip or Overwrite All when running the following bat?

Tags: windows, batch

How would I Pipe in Skip or Overwrite All (Always) to the following code?

NB! the code recursively extracts archives with folders and sub-archives.

```
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
 pushd %CD%
 cd %%F
     FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
         "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%X"
     )
 popd
)
```

See below an example of the prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" -?` shows a `-y` switch:

> ```
> -y : assume Yes on all queries
> ```

In any case, `7z.exe` accepts [input from pipeline](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html); you can send `(A)lways` as

```
echo A|"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%~X"
```

or `(S)kip all` as

```
echo S|"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%~X"
```

or `A(u)to rename all` as

```
echo u|"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%~X"
```

or `(Q)uit` as

```
echo Q|"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%~X"
```